# How to handle an empty search query in Laravel 9?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I'm currently trying to implement a search functionality in my Laravel 9 API. Unfortunately, when I leave an empty query the API returns absolutely nothing. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Route:

```php
Route::get('/products/search/{title?}', 'searchTitle');
```

```php
public function searchTitle(Request $request, $title = '')
{
    $pageSize = $request->page_size ?? 10;

    if ($title == '') {
        return Product::query()->paginate($pageSize);
    } else {
        return Product::where('title', 'LIKE', "%$title%")
            ->paginate($pageSize);
    }
}
```

Comment: So if you have value in `$title` it returns something?

Comment: @aceraven777 that's right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use [Conditional Clauses (`when`)](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#conditional-clauses), something like this:

```
return Product::when($title !== '', function (Builder $query, $title) {
    return $query->where('title', 'LIKE', "%$title%");
})
    ->paginate($pageSize);
```

Or use the object assign to a variable and make the where

```
 $product = Product::query();

 if ($title !== '') {
     $product->where('title', 'LIKE', "%$title%");
 }
 
 return $product->paginate($pageSize);
```

Comment: cheers! I rewrote it using conditional clauses and got something like this 
`return Product::query()->when($request->query("title"), function($query, $title) {
            $query->where("title", "LIKE", "%" . $title . "%")->paginate($pageSize);`
this seems to work, thanks!

Comment: Looks good but, uses the **$title** var instead of **$request->query("title")** in **when** clausule, just for keep the code more clear. 
But works, that is the important.